# Why is the -ing form used after 'therefore' in this example ("[...] therefore reducing emissions.")?

Tags: conjunctions, syntax

I can't understand why the writer used -ing form of verb in my example after conjunctive adverb "therefore".

However, I know that 'therefore', 'however', 'hence', 'nevertheless', .. are conjunctive adverbs. They have to connect two independent clauses.

I am still confused why we use 'ing' form after adverbs, because we often use 'ing' form after prepositions not adverbs.

> "They could also impose ‘green taxes’ on drivers and airline
>   companies. In this way, people would be encouraged to use public
>   transport and (they would be encourage**d**) to take fewer flights abroad,
>   **therefore** reducing emissions."

Comment: It should be **thereby**

Answer (score 1):

"Reducing emissions" is a participle phrase that is part of a larger adverbial clause "therefore reducing emissions" which modifies the sentence's verb (which modifies *would encourage*).

What may make this a bit more confusing is that the sentence uses a passive construction and the subject of the sentence, *governments* is only implied and never actually appears, so in the interest of making this analysis easier, it might be easier if we rewrote the sentence using an active form:

> In this way, governments would encourage people to use public transport
>   and to take fewer flights abroad, therefore reducing emissions.

*Therefore*, along with *hence* and *thus*, can introduce a adverbial phrase formed with a present participle.  As explained here:

> Hence, therefore or thus can be added immediately before an adverbial
>   phrase showing result https://learningenglishgrammar.wordpress.com/adverbial-phrases-with-present-participles/

Notice the example sentence from the site above:  "They introduced certain rulers, (hence / therefore or thus) complicating things."